# How to control list of Apps shown when starting Intent?

Tags: android, pdf, android-intent

I want to start an Intent to open/view a PDF I have just created.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
intent.setDataAndType(path, "application/pdf");
intent.setData(path);
this.startActivity(intent);
```

This pops up a "Select an action" dialog with two options:

- Android System
- Browser

If I choose Android System, THEN it'll give me another dialog box which show the list of apps capable of showing a PDF.

How do I skip that first dialog and jump right to dialog with the list of apps?

Comment: Have you looked at `ACTION_CHOOSER` http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_CHOOSER and/or the associated `Intent.createChooser(...)` convenience method?

Comment: All that does it bring up the aforementioned Android System/Browser chooser.

Comment: I wondered if that may be the case which is why I posted as comment rather than an answer. BTW, I notice you `setDataAndType(...)` then call `setData(...)`. From the docs for `setData` - "Set the data this intent is operating on. This method automatically clears any type that was previously set by setType(String).". I don't know if the clearing of 'type' is also happening in your code and perhaps confusing the issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try getting rid of the `setData()` call. It is redundant, in that you are setting the `Uri` in `setDataAndType()`, and you are wiping out your MIME type by calling `setData()` after `setDataAndType()`.

Comment: Thanks, that was it. I didn't realize I still had it left over from the first pass of the code.